# Correction Needed for Error in Access Query

Tags: ms-access

I want to create a table [Top Stores] that has 10 most active stores in terms of quantity of product sold. Each store sells 3 products. I just need to add the quantity sold for each product to arrive at StoreSale. **The problem is when there is no sale for a product, the quantity value is left blank and not 0.** I try to change the blank to 0 by the isnull tests. Please point out the error in my code below:

```
SELECT top 10  StoreName, StoreSale = (iif (isnull(Product1), 0, Product1) + iif (isnull(Product2), 0, Product2) + iif (isnull(Product3), 0, Product3)) INTO [Top Stores]
FROM SaleTable ORDER BY StoreSale DESC;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Two things:

1. if you use `=`, you will be doing an equality test, you can't have an assignment like that in SQL.
   You will need to name your calculated result `AS StoreSale` instead.
2. Use `Nz()` to get a `0.00` when the field value is `NULL`

Result:

```sql
SELECT TOP 10 StoreName,
              Nz(product1) + Nz(Product2) + Nz(Product3) AS StoreSale
INTO   [Top Stores]
FROM   SaleTable
ORDER  BY StoreSale DESC;
```